# Comparing two instantances of the same activerecord object returns false if attr_accessible is present Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, activerecord, compare

Using Ruby 1.9.3 and ActiveRecord 3.2.6.

I'm having an issue when trying to compare an ActiveRecord Object that has attr_accessible :property set on it, that is contained in an Array of associated Objects using include?(object).

These are my 2 ActiveRecord models, Account and Role.

Account:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  #
  has_many :role_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, :through => :role_assignments
end
```

Role:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title

  # Associations
  #
  has_many :role_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :accounts, :through => :role_assignments
end
```

If I then create a couple of Roles (say "Admin" and "Editor") and assign the "Admin" one to an Account, I would assume this would work:

```
role = Role.find_by_title("Admin")
account = Account.first # => The Account we assigned the "Admin" role to

account.roles.include?(role) # => Should be true but returns false
```

But this actually returns false!

If I remove the 'attr_accessible :title' from the Role model and repeat the above then it does return true.

So I guess my question is... why would attr_accessible cause this particular issue? or is it a case that I have to do my check to see if role does exist in account.roles a different way?

Comment: How did you create your roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try that

```
account.role_ids.include?(role.id)
```

Comment: Yep that worked, Thanks @yuri. Do you off hand know why it doesn't work on the Object directly?

Comment: I think the objects themselves have some attributes with unique identifiers, memory allocation and mri would require it, I think that's correct anyway.